# Get the path of the .dmg from the mount point

Tags: macos, diskimage

I'm looking for a way to get the .dmg path of a mounted disk image with just its mount point.

I want to write a "simple" Finder service that ejects the disk image and trashes the accompanying .dmg. The ejecting is trivial, but I'm at a loss as to how to figure out the path of the .dmg, given just the mount point.

**diskutil** doesn't seem to know or isn't saying.

It's for a script, so AppleScript- or shell-based suggestions are preferred.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get an AppleScript or shell based suggestion because you're probably going to have to talk to the driver, or at least its user agent, for that.

Comment: I thought there might be something like hdiutil or diskutil that could help, or perhaps a Finder property on mounted disk images.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `hdiutil info` to get the information about currently mounted images. Then
use `hdiutil detach /Mount/Point` to dismount all file systems, and detach the image.

You'll need to parse the output from `hdiutil info` to find the right image-path if multiple images are mounted.  It will probably be more robust to use the plist output format `hdiutil info -plist` and run that into, say, a python script with [plistlib](http://docs.python.org/library/plistlib.html) or an AppleScript using the `Property List Suite` from `System Events`.

Here's a quick and dirty python script to give you an idea.  It's easy to explore options using the python interpreter:

```
>>> import plistlib
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> output = Popen(["hdiutil", "info", "-plist"], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
>>> pl = plistlib.readPlistFromString(output)
>>> for image in pl['images']:
...   for se in image['system-entities']:
...       if se.get('mount-point') == '/Volumes/blah':
...          print image['image-path']
/Path/To/blah.dmg
```

Comment: That won't help me trash the .dmg, though.

Comment: Brilliant! hdiutil info is just what I'm looking for!

Comment: @wbg @NedDeily I'm reading this in 2019 and cannot get the suggested solution to work. Has the `hdiutil` program changed? When I run it I only get information about the framework and driver versions.

Comment: @NeilBartlett Do you have any disk images mounted? The framework/driver info is normal. There's an additional `images` array when there are images mounted.

Comment: @wbg Yes, I have two images mounted.

Answer (score 4):

Start Terminal, do:

```
$ cd /Volumes
$ hdiutil info
```

The location of suspected dmg-files will show up under image-path

`cd` to that location, and do:

```
$ ls filename
```

Unmount volume in Finder, and finally in Terminal:

```
$ rm filename
```

Good luck.